# .append() to a Collection of custom Structs

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have a custom `struct` made for Creating, Shuffling and Dealing Playing cards.

```
struct Card {
    let pip : Pip
    let suit : Suit

    var isFaceCard : Bool {
        return pip.rawValue > 10
    }

    var color : CardColor {
        return suit.color
    }
}
```

Secondly I have a Dictionary of players initialised with each player having a Collection of Cards.

```
 var Players = ["Scott": [Card](), "Bob": [Card](), "John": [Card]()]
```

To effectively deal from my already shuffled deck, I plan to loop through the players' dictionary twice and deal one card per time, as would happen live.

Is it possible to simple append a Card type to the Card collection? My attempts haven't seemed to work. `d` being a shuffled **Deck** (**Collection**) of **Card** types.

```
Players["Scott"].append(d.deal())
```

---

### EDIT1

With using Structs for each Player i have added this

```
struct Player {
   let name : String
   var cards : [Card]
}
var Players = [Player]()
Players.append(Player(name:"Scott"))
```

Do i have to give the player their "cards" upon initialisation or can i deal them at a later time? As the above code produces an error.

```
Players.append(Player(name:"Scott", cards: [Card]()))
```

Would the above be correct?

Comment: If a player can possess an array of cards, then a Player should be a struct and it should contain an array of cards as property. I suggest to not use dictionaries at all here.

Comment: That's a great idea, I shall try that and report back

Comment: Remember you can [edit] your question if needed. :)

Comment: I thought the same thing mid comment spam :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Direct answer:*

If a player can possess an array of cards, then a Player should be a struct and this struct should contain an array of cards as property. I suggest not using dictionaries at all here.

*After your edit:*

You're on the right track.

You don't *have to* give the player their cards at initialization if you create an initializer yourself for your struct:

```
struct Player {
    let name : String
    var cards : [Card] = []

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Doing so cancels the automatic generation of a memberwise initializer and only yours will be available.

But if you want to keep the automatic memberwise initializer, you can pass an empty array of cards like this at initialization:

```
struct Player {
    let name : String
    var cards : [Card]
}

let joe = Player(name: "Joe", cards: [])
```

*After your comments:*

If you have all your players in an array, you can fetch a specific player by using `indexOf` with a closure predicate, like this for example:

```
struct Player {
    let name : String
    var cards : [Card] = []

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func fold() {
        print("\(name) just folded")
    }
}

var players = [Player]()
players.append(Player(name: "Joe"))
players.append(Player(name: "Jane"))
players.append(Player(name: "Jack"))
players.append(Player(name: "Janice"))

if let janeIndex = players.indexOf({ $0.name == "Jane" }) {
    players[janeIndex].fold()
}
```

Let's say you want all players to fold but one, you could use `filter`:

```
let notJack = players.filter { $0.name != "Jack" }
notJack.forEach { $0.fold() }
```

Comment: Ahh, i understand. Separately would there be a 'correct' way to access each player by name for example if i needed to **fold** a specific player?

Comment: Which could be another property of the player eg "status"

Comment: I've added examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to pick your brain one last time. Is there any other concept that come to mind that I should be aware of in the Card game scenario?

Comment: You're welcome. Be aware of the difference between structs and classes  (value vs reference) and you'll be ok. // I suppose you could have a look at my PokerHands repo: https://github.com/ericdke/PokerHands to discover similar techniques. It's far from perfect but there's good stuff in it. ;)

Comment: Ahah, yes, I see that. :p It was written with the first version of Swift 3 and lots have changed since. I'll update soon (probably this week-end). Still, given your current task, having a look at the model files (player, card, etc) could be useful.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking through it atm. :)

Comment: Actually the errors where trivial and it was easy to fix. New version has been pushed, works in Xcode 8 beta 3 now. ;)

Comment: Weird, still has 60+ Errors on mine :s